# how to bind value RadzenTextBox blazor

Tags: binding, textbox, blazor-server-side

iam trying to use Rdzen library into a form and i use its textbox but its not working when i want to use the @bind-Value=item.Value propertie ...
ineed to get the value of the textbox when i submit the form but don't know how with this library

[image: here my code]

when i use this it work but no bindind to the object

```
<RadzenTextBox Placeholder=@item.Value style="width: 100%;" Name=@item.Key />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my pb seems to be because of the dictonary where i loop to bind with the value of it....

To bind, in my case i find the solution by binding an object variable like

```
 public class FilTemp
    {
        public string key { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }

    }
                    List<FilTemp> listFilTemps = new List<FilTemp>();
                    @foreach (var item in listFilTemps)
                    {
                        <div class="align-items-center d-flex col-md-5">
                            <RadzenLabel Style="font-style:italic" Text=@item.key />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-7">

                            <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value=item.value style="width: 100%;" />

                        </div>
                        
                    }
```

It worked.